# add different functions to different videoID

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, api, youtube

I would like to add to each video in a list of video IDs (YT API) different events such as: show an image while the video is playing, every time you go to a next video load a different image. Could you help me to understand how to implement the code? This is a visual example

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color:grey;">

<div id="player" style="position:absolute;top: 0%;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 5%);z-index:10"></div>
<div id="pulsanti" style="position:absolute;top: 5%;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 420px);">
<button class="button" id="previous">PREVIOUS</button>
<button class="button" id="play-button">PLAY</button>
<button class="button" id="pause-button" >PAUSE</button>
<button class="button" id="next">NEXT</button>
<button class="button" id="stop-button">STOP</button>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 0%;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 35px);" ><img src="01.png" id="slide" alt="" width="500" height="300" ></div>
<div class="buttons" id="controls"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = 
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, 
firstScriptTag);


var videoIDs = [
  'RGpr3Y6Q-1M',   /* video1 */
  'btxdcqLOGuc',   /* video2 */
  'CIx0a1vcYPc'  /* video3 */
];


var player, currentVideoId = 0;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '450',
    width: '800',
    playerVars: {
      controls: 1,
      showinfo: 0,
      rel: 0,
      showsearch: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      autoplay: 1,
      mute: 1
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
  
    // bind events
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.playVideo();
    });

    var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
    pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.pauseVideo();
    });

    var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-button");
    stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.stopVideo();
    });
 var next = document.getElementById("next");
    next.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.nextVideo();
    });
    
 var pre = document.getElementById("previous");
    pre.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.previousVideo();
    });
    
     player.loadPlaylist( {
        playlist:videoIDs
    } );
    
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    currentVideoId++;
    if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
      player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body></html>
```

They suggested I add the images as for the videoIDs, but I don't know how to connect the events

```
var images = [
  'image1.png',    /* about-video1 */
  'image2.png',    /* about-video2 */
  'image3.png'     /* about-video3 */
];
```

Comment: Hi Andy and welcome to SO. If you haven't yet, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the current state you've expressed a wish. However, there is neither a question nor a problem stated. Please edit your question by specifically stating what problem you're having and how we can help you solve it. Thanks!

Comment: I modified my problem and request, I hope I have given all the elements for a sufficient evaluation

Comment: This is much better. Could you also include the HTML regarding the **player** element and the **image** element in which you're trying to put your media? We'll need to be able to select those elements to create the player and to place the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to connect an image to a video id is to pair them in an object. With this pattern you'll get sets of id's and images that correspond with each other.

I've made an object with keys that represent the `id` of the video and values that represent the image `src` of the video.

Whenever a video start buffering, the `playlist` is retrieved. This is an array of strings representing the ids of the videos. Then the current index in the playlist is retrieved to select the current playing id from the playlist.

Now we have the current id, and with it, we can select the image that goes with the id from the object we created before.

```html
<div id="player" style="position:absolute;top: 0%;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 5%);z-index:10"></div>
<div id="pulsanti" style="position:absolute;top: 5%;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 420px); z-index:11;">
<button class="button" id="previous">PREVIOUS</button>
<button class="button" id="play-button">PLAY</button>
<button class="button" id="pause-button" >PAUSE</button>
<button class="button" id="next">NEXT</button>
<button class="button" id="stop-button">STOP</button>
<div style="position:absolute;top: 0%;left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 35px);" ><img src="01.png" id="slide" alt="" width="500" height="300" ></div>
<div class="buttons" id="controls"></div>
```

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

const playerElement = document.querySelector('#player');
const imageElement = document.querySelector('#slide');

const videos = {
  'RGpr3Y6Q-1M': 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature',
  'btxdcqLOGuc': 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/people',
  'CIx0a1vcYPc': 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech'
};

// Create an array of ids from the videos array.
const videoIds = Object.keys(videos);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  function onPlayerReady({ target }) {
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.playVideo();
    });

    var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
    pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.pauseVideo();
    });

    var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-button");
    stopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.stopVideo();
    });

    var next = document.getElementById("next");
    next.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.nextVideo();
    });
      
    var pre = document.getElementById("previous");
    pre.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.previousVideo();
    });
      
    target.loadPlaylist({
      playlist: videoIds
    });
  }

  // Whenever a video ends, load the next video.
  function onPlayerStateChange({ data, target }) {
    switch(data) {
      case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
        target.nextVideo();
        break;

      case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
        const playlist = target.getPlaylist();
        const playlistIndex = target.getPlaylistIndex();
        const currentId = playlist[playlistIndex];
        const image = videos[currentId];

        if (imageElement.src !== image) {
          imageElement.src = image;
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  const player = new YT.Player(playerElement, {
    height: '505',
    width: '900',
    playerVars: {
      controls: 0,
      showinfo: 0,
      rel: 0,
      showsearch: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      autoplay: 1,
      mute: 1
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I re-entered the complete code to understand how it should work and the position of the uploaded image for each videoID

Comment: now the code dont work on custom buttons :-(

Comment: You kinda changed the code last minute there, buddy. I'll take another look.

Comment: Ho risolto!! Grazie Emiel ;-)

Comment: Non c’è problema!

Comment: Sorry Emiel, how can i create a loop from last video and first video or viceversa ?

Comment: @Andy, that sounds like a new question. Be sure to make a new post for it. And do research on the YT Iframe API to see if it supports looped playlists.

Comment: I have try to make a new question but without soluzion :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456190/how-make-a-loop-array-youtube-videos