# how make a loop array youtube videos?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, constants, var

I want to loop this video list with image attached: when the last video ends the first one of the list starts, how is it possible to do it?

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

const playerElement = document.querySelector('#player');
const imageElement = document.querySelector('#slide');

const videos = {
  'RGpr3Y6Q-1M': 'image1.png',
  'btxdcqLOGuc': 'image2.png',
  'CIx0a1vcYPc': 'image3.png',
  '6-4KydP92ss': 'image4.png'
};
```

I want to loop this video list with image attached: when the last video ends the first one of the list starts, how is it possible to do it? This part about the custom buttons.

```
const videoIds = Object.keys(videos);

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  function onPlayerReady({ target }) {
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.playVideo();
    });
    
    var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
    pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.pauseVideo();
    });  

    var next = document.getElementById("next");
    next.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.nextVideo();
    });
      
    var pre = document.getElementById("previous");
    pre.addEventListener("click", function() {
      target.previousVideo();
    });
      
    target.loadPlaylist({
      playlist: videoIds
    });
  }

function onPlayerStateChange({ data, target }) {
    switch(data) {
      case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
        target.nextVideo();
        break;

      case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
        const playlist = target.getPlaylist();
        const playlistIndex = target.getPlaylistIndex();
        const currentId = playlist[playlistIndex];
        const image = videos[currentId];

        if (imageElement.src !== image) {
          imageElement.src = image;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

and this my YT player

```
    const player = new YT.Player(playerElement, {
    height: '405',
    width: '720',
    playerVars: {
      controls: 1,
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.
We are starting by creating array of objects first.
Then we need to iterate and restrict iterator according to length of our array.

```js
const videos = [
    {id : 'RGpr3Y6Q-1M', img : 'image1.png'},
    {id : 'btxdcqLOGuc', img :  'mage2.png'},
   {id:  'CIx0a1vcYPc' , img :  'mage3.png'},
   {id :  '6-4KydP92ss' , img : 'mage4.png'} 
];

  var num =-1 ; 
  
  pickTheVideo =(  )=>{
    num = num + 1 
    if( num > videos.length -1  ){   num =-1  ;  return ( pickTheVideo( ) ) }
    
    return videos[ num ]
    
  }
 
for (let index = 0; index < 10   ; index++) {
    const videoObj = pickTheVideo() ;
    console.log( index , "videoObj" , videoObj )
}
```

Comment: I tried to add your code but it doesn't work, jsfiddle.net/6p5sf392 what did i do wrong?